# How to get the data from a object?

Tags: c#, listview, object, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a Listview with values. When i select a item, i pass a object with all values to another page and i want to show all the values, but is not appearing.
Object "envolvselect" has 4 values (NomePesquisa, NomeMae, NomePai and DtNasc) and i want to show them... when i debug, the values are passing correct. The problem is to show them!

[Page 1]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AppMobile.Services;
using AppMobile.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AppMobile.Views
{
    public partial class BuscaEnvolvidos : ContentPage
    {
        public BuscaEnvolvidos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }

        public void ConsultarClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ListaDados = new ListView();

            string nomepesquisa = entryNmPesq.Text;
            string nomemae = entryNmMae.Text;
            string nomepai = entryNmPai.Text;
            string dtnasc = entrydtNasc.Text;

            ApiCall apiCall = new ApiCall();

            apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvidos>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomepesquisa, nomemae, nomepai, dtnasc).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //Caso tenha erro na requisição
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        DisplayAlert("Erro", "Ocorreu um erro na Requisição. Tente novamente", "Ok");
                    });
                }

                //Caso a requisição ocorra sem problemas, cairemos aqui
                else
                {
                    //Se Chegarmos aqui, está tudo ok, agora itemos tratar nossa Lista
                    //Aqui Usaremos a Thread Principal, ou seja, a que possui as references da UI
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ListaDados.ItemsSource = t.Result;
                        Navigation.PushAsync(new ResultadosBuscados(ListaDados.ItemsSource));
                    });

                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

[Page 2]

```
namespace AppMobile.Views
{
   public partial class ResultadosBuscados : ContentPage
    {
        public ResultadosBuscados(IEnumerable dadosPesquisados)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListaBuscados.ItemsSource = dadosPesquisados;

        }

        public void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var envolvSelec = e.SelectedItem;
                if (envolvSelec == null)
                    return;

            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new EnvolvidoDetalhe(envolvSelec));
            this.ListaBuscados.SelectedItem = null;
        }

    }
}
```

[Page 3]

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppMobile.Views
{
    public partial class EnvolvidoDetalhe : ContentPage
    {
        private object envolvSelec;

        public EnvolvidoDetalhe(object envolvSelec)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.envolvSelec = envolvSelec;
        }

    }
}
```

On the Page 3 i binded the labels, so in .xaml is:

```
        <ListView x:Name="ListaInfos" SeparatorColor="#F4B400" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout Spacing="1">
            <Label x:Name="lblNome" Text="{Binding NomePesquisa}" TextColor="#555" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblNomeMae" Text="{Binding NomeMae}" TextColor="#555" FontSize="12"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblNomePai" Text="{Binding NomePai}" TextColor="#555" FontSize="12"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="lblDataNasc" Text="{Binding DtNasc}" TextColor="#555" FontSize="12" ></Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the `BindingContext` in your page 3 Xaml or code.

You can assign it as such:

```
public EnvolvidoDetalhe(object envolvSelec)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.envolvSelec = envolvSelec;
    BindingContext = envolvSelec;
}
```

Now your bound labels in know which object to obtain their data from via that object's public properties (NomePesquisa, NomeMae, etc....).

Comment: My hero !!!! rsrsrs
Thanks my friend...
Let me ask you another thing... when i do {Binding}, how can i show a string before ? Like this:

"Name:" (RESULT OF BINDING)

Now, im just showing (result of binding)

Comment: I discovered "{Binding NomePesquisa, StringFormat='Nome: {0}'}"
Also, thank you so much !!!